# Natural operators in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

Which operators in differential geometry is called natural? And this neutrality is respect to what property or structure? Why this is an important problem? and what is due problem relations with lie algebras or derivations of them?
And what is the exact meaning of naturality through examples please?

Comment: You might look at Kolar's book, "Naturality in Differential Geometry," which has a free PDF under Google. Naturality means vaguely that an operator is defined in a way that doesn't use properties of the object it's defined on, and has a precise definition in category theory. All in all, this question admits only a very long answer, if any.